# How to send JSON in php via jquery correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm sending *JSON* to backend server, but I'm confuse about how I can process it correctly,
i'm reading around that `echo (json_decode($_POST));` is not going to work but
`echo (json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));`, but actually I tried to output the response on the client side `alert(respon);` but nothing show

*0_12_e2_contentType_JSON.html*

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script >

    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "fragment/0_12_e2_contentType_JSON.php",
            type: "POST",
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",

            data: {
                "name":"hans" ,
                "id":10
            },
            success: function (respon)
            {
               alert(respon);
            },
            error:function(e){
            alert('Ajaxnya error');
               }
        });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*0_12_e2_contentType_JSON.php*

```
<?php
echo (json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));
?>
```

My question is that is it already correct? but why does it output nothing? Thanks

Comment: `var_dump` might work better in this case

Comment: Change it to `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));` and see if it works?

Comment: Hello I tried but it ouput `NULL`

Comment: @Bravo ^^ How did you check that? What's your PHP version?

Comment: `alert()` php 5.6 @PraveenKumar :)

Comment: you aren't serializing the json . Simpler to use `$_POST` and remove the `contentType`

Comment: Remove this `contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",` and see?

Comment: @charlietfl, yes friend, that's exactly makes me confuse, I mean what's the point of `contentType` or How can I just send JSON, and go to sleep peacefully

Comment: @charlietfl Hey! I don't think we need `.serialize()` or something there?

Comment: @Bravo You don't need that.

Comment: if you want to sent `application/json` you need to stringify it yourself

Comment: @charlietfl, That's it bro that's actually works!!! could you put it as the answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send `contentType:'application/json'` you need to stringify the data yourself

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "fragment/0_12_e2_contentType_JSON.php",
        type: "POST",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",

        data: JSON.stringify({ "name":"hans" ,"id":10}),
        success: function (respon)
        {
           alert(respon);
        },
        error:function(e){
        alert('Ajaxnya error');
           }
    });
```

Most people would not override the default `contentType` and receive in php using `$_POST`

Comment: $_POST won't work with me (somehow it *will* has to do with  the `contentType`)

Comment: in fact ...you can send it as 
`data:data: { "name":"hans" ,"id":10}` and then use `json_encode($_POST)` on srv

Comment: @fedeghe not if you override default contentType

Comment: Maybe *contentType* just means to be indicating the type of request body I sent, but not converting the data that I sent . Well I'm a bit new to JQuery :D , thanks Anyone . @fedeghe, I will give you upvote if you change your answer, coz I'm sending JSON *not* to receive it :D

Comment: @Bravo you are making it more complicated than it needs to be by adding your own contentType. See my update at bottom of answer. Read the docs to understand difference between `dataType` and `contentType`

Comment: dear @Bravo... thank You for the undue explanation... I wont sell it for an upvote, I really do not care, has no value ... You're sending a literal, the easiest way is to use a framework as u do, and I't so funny to see how such a thing can cause problems.

Comment: @fedeghe, If I know that will cause a problem then why would I ask that anyway? you should already know that when I said `contentType` i'm sending to server, if wrote `dataType` i'm receiving from the server :) btw don't cry hehe, I will give +10 to your another post . Not here (coz I downvote it, sorry)

Comment: Thanks for your helps everyone, I'm going to logout,.

Comment: @Bravo again strange way, from cli is not mandatory and usually is done via header in php ....anyway, bravo! You got it! :D

Answer (score -2):

not clear to me Your question anyway it seems like in the end You want to answer from the server what You sended via ajax... if it is the case I would recommend to use json_encode ... not json_decode

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo (json_encode($_POST));
?>
```

Comment: I mean I'm sending JSON :D

Comment: `json_encode()` is wrong ... `file_get_contents()` returns string

Comment: really? ... so You're missing something cause json_decode takes a string ..can't take an array (I'm looking at Your question)
btw...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script

so anyway You should use the right header before the response

    `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: I'll downvote Your question cause in the end You accepted an answer that IS NOT `How to send JSON in php via jquery correctly`.
Maybe no one will ever rely on it

Comment: well at least you told me that you were the one downvoted me *:D* hahahah, no problem mate! please just don't take it personally ;)